# Proof of the inequality $2^{n} < \binom{2n}{n} < 2^{2n}$?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

As review for a midterm I am asked to prove the inequality:
$2^{n} < \binom{2n}{n} < 2^{2n}, n > 1.$

What I have is a two-part inductive proof. It is not hard to show for $2^{n} < \binom{2n}{n}$:

**Base step:**

Let $n=2$:

$2^{2} < \frac{(2n)!}{2!2!} < 2^{2*2}$

$4 < 6 < 16$

**Inductive Step:**

Show $2^{k+1} < \frac{[2(k+1)]!}{(k+1)!(k+1)!}.$

We have
$2^{k+1} = 2^{k}*2,$

so

$2^{k+1} < 2 * \frac{2k!}{k!k!}.$

Since

$\frac{(2k+2)!}{(k+1)*k!*(k+1)*k!} = \frac{2(k+1)*(2k+1)*2k!}{(k+1)k!(k+1)k!} = (2k+1) * \frac{2k!}{k!k!}$

and

$(2k+1) > 2, k \geq 2,$

we can conclude the first part of the inequality. However, I can't make the second part work. By similar algebra I arrive at:

$(2k+1) * \frac{2k}{k!k!} < 2^{2(k+1)} = 2^{2k}*2^{2},$

but

$ (2k+1) \nless 4, k \geq 2.$

What have I done wrong?

Comment: The ratio between consecutive terms is $\frac{2k+1}{k+1}$, not $2k+1$.

Comment: Note that ${2n\choose n}<\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n\choose k}=(1+1)^{2n}$.

Answer (score 8):

You may avoid induction. We have

$$ \binom{2n}{n}=\frac{2n}{n}\cdot\frac{2n-1}{n-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{n+1}{2}>2^n $$
since every factor of the middle term, except the very first one, is greater than $2$.
On the other hand,
$$ \binom{2n}{n}<\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k} = 2^{2n} = 4^n $$
by the binomial theorem.

Comment: I don't understand why $\binom{2n}{n}$ equals that, since $\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{2n!}{(2n-n)!n!} = \frac{2n!}{n!n!}.$

Comment: @user327716: $\frac{(2n)!}{n!}=(2n)(2n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+1)$.

Comment: Oh. I see! I didn't see that the series ended at n+1.

Comment: It appears that the last term of the first part is not greater, but at least equal if $n<4$. $\frac{2n}{n}$ is obviously 2, but the last term must have $n \geq 4$. Is that correct?

Comment: @user327716: let we put it this way: the sequence given by $a_k=\frac{2n-k}{n-k}$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,(n-1)$ is increasing with respect to $k$.

Comment: Indeed it is! And since only the first term is exactly 2, we can easily say that the sequence is greater than $2^{n}$, because every term would have to not be greater in order to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. Using the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we have $$\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-n}\leq n!\leq n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{1-n}
 $$ hence $$\dbinom{2n}{n}=\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{n!^{2}}\leq\frac{e}{\sqrt{2}\pi n^{1/2}}4^{n}<\color{red}{4^{n}}
 $$ and $$\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{n!^{2}}\geq\frac{\sqrt{\pi}2^{2n+1}}{n^{1/2}e^{2}}>\color{red}{2^{n}}.$$